# How to map the opportunities with the contacts in dynamic crm?

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working with MS dynamic CRM 2013 and my task is to import the data in the CRM which i already have in the correct template. I have already imported contacts and trying to import the respective contact's opportunities but while doing so system gives an error that "A duplicate reference lookup was found". This is due to the reason that there are multiple contacts with same name and whenever system finds duplicate contacts, it does not map the corresponding opportunity.

Could anyone help me to map the opportunities with their respective contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough names are same emails should be unique. In that case map opportunity to contact using emailaddress instead of name.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Opportunity can only be mapped to opportunity entity. If i map with the contact, It will try to create another contact and not opportunity. I don't think it will work.

Comment: Map the Opportunity entity to the Opportunity. But in the next step when you associate the fields map, you will be associating the contact data. Since the contact is a lookup you have to set the field in contact which has to be resolved. It can be any field from the contact entity. You might have used the contact name because of which the lookup was not resolved (becoz of duplicate contact names). Here instead of associating with contact name, you can try with the contact email. Which will be more unique than name. Hope now you are clear on above approach. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: I tried doing the same by since email field is not a part of opportunity entity, i can't see that mapping field present in opportunity.

Comment: Can you please share your email ID? I can send you the screenshot for the same.

Comment: Sure. Here is my email : sumit_ruhela@hotmail.com. Thanks.

Comment: Sumit, Screenshot has been shared to your email address. Let me know whether that helped.

Comment: Can we connect on Phone to discuss this? Here is my contact Info: 09811441125